# pyodbc.Error when trying to open jet database

Tags: python, ms-access, pyodbc

I'm trying to read data stored in a ms access database that generated by a piece of software [Hy Tek Meet Manager](http://www.hy-tekltd.com/track-meet-management.html)

```
import pyodbc

filename = 'db.mdb'

connection = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ='+filename)
cursor = conn.cursor()
```

When I run this code I get the error:

```
pyodbc.Error: ('IM002', '[IM002] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnectW)')
```

All other searches for this error have led to dead ends. Any suggestions as to why this is happening?

Comment: Have you tried putting in the full path to `db.mdb`?

Comment: @ChristopheD That doesn't resolve the error.  I'm working off of [this guide](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Database_Programming)if that helps at all.

Comment: What OS are you doing this in?

Comment: ubuntu 10.10.  Do I  need to be running windows for ODBC to work?

Comment: I do not know these guys http://www.easysoft.com/products/data_access/odbc-access-driver/index.html and I have not tried the drivers, but when I saw it, I though it might be of interest to you.

Comment: thank you but i have them installed already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on one of your comments it sounds like you are using the EasySoft MS Access ODBC drivers.  Referencing their [support page](http://www.easysoft.com/products/data_access/odbc-access-driver/manual/configuration.html#882975), I would guess the following is what you want to use for your connection string:

```
import pyodbc

filename = 'db.mdb'

connection = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Easysoft ODBC-ACCESS}; MDBFILE='+filename)
cursor = conn.cursor()
```